# compiler error C2448 returning a std stream

Tags: c++, stream, compiler-errors

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++ program where I have my own stream implementation. Something like this:

```
class Foo : public std::ostream
{
public:
    Foo( int a ) : std::ostream( &buf_ ) { };
    Foo( boost::shared_ptr< int > a ) : std::ostream( &buf_ ) { };
private:
    std::filebuf buf_;
};

class Bar
{
public:
    Foo GetFoo() { return Foo( 1 ); };
    Foo GetFoo2() { return Foo( boost::shared_ptr< int >( new int( 1 ) ) ); };
};
```

The intended usage is like this:

```
Bar b;
Foo f = b.GetFoo(); // works fine
Foo f2 = b.GetFoo2(); // compiler error
```

Unfortunately, this gives me a compiler error about the basic_ios copy constructor.

```
error C2248: 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>'
```

Why is the first `Foo( int )` constructor okay with the compiler, but the one involving a `boost::shared_ptr` is not?

Thanks,
PaulH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Foo` class is inheriting from a non-copyable class, yet you are not implementing the copy constructor. You are bound to get into trouble when you pass instances of `Foo` by value, as you do in the getter functions.

The reason that `GetFoo` works might be that return-value optimization is eliding the copy construction, but this doesn't mean that you're allowed to do this.

Comment: I'm compiling in debug mode, so I'm surprised RVO is turned on.
Can you implement a copy constructor when deriving from a class that makes its copy constructor private?

Comment: It could be a combination of RVO and inlining... if you really want to check, you could put the `get` function in a separate TU.